# How to write queries using JOIN operator?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Consider the following schema:

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

The key fields are underlined, and the domain of each field is listed after the field name.
Thus sid is the key for Suppliers, pid is the key for Parts, and sid and pid together
form the key for Catalog. The Catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by
Suppliers.

Now I am trying to solve this SQL statement -

```
Find the sids of suppliers who supply some red part and some green part.
```

I came up with this SQL query but not sure whether this is right or not -

```
SELECT C.sid
FROM Parts P, Catalog C
WHERE P.color = `red' AND P.pid = C.pid
AND EXISTS ( SELECT P2.pid
FROM Parts P2, Catalog C2
WHERE P2.color = `green' AND C2.sid = C.sid
AND P2.pid = C2.pid )
```

Is there any way, I can write the above same query using JOIN operator. Exists operator is confusing me slightly.. And what is the easiest way to write the above query?

Comment: why use exists ? when you can simply `join 3 tables then where <>`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.sid
FROM Catalog AS C
INNER JOIN Parts AS P
    ON C.pid = P.pid
INNER JOIN Suppliers AS S
    ON C.sid = S.sid
WHERE P.color = `red' AND P.color = `green'
```

Answer (score 0):

The objective is to find supplier(s) whom supply both green and red parts from the catalog.

Thus I create a "green" alias for the catalog and part and a "red" alias for the catalog and part and I inner join them to insure that only suppliers whom supply both types of parts will be in the result set.

Also, one could have multiple parts which are red and green for a given supplier, thus I choose to use a "select distinct" instead of "select".

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cr.sid 
FROM Parts Pg,
    Parts Pr,
    Catalog Cg, 
    Catalog Cr 
 WHERE
     Cg.sid = Cr.sid
     AND Cg.pid = Pg.pid
     AND Cr.pid = Pr.pid
     AND Pr.color = 'red'
     AND Pg.color = 'green'
```